# How do i resize bmp images in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to resize bmp images in codeigniter. How do i do that. Codeigniter image manipulation class resizes only images of type jpg,png and gif....Please help some one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the gd module installed for php. Then either extend the CI image manipulation class to work with bmp images or just resize them directly in the controller. Either way, you will need to familiarize yourself with the gd functions:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out Timthumb, it's a much better solution to resize images than CI's built in functions, which are a little confusing.